# How to INSERT query a list of elements in python

Tags: python

I have tried to query all elements from a list into an insertion query, I tried by making the list into a list of tuples and directly by adding the elements from the list. But it did not work, and I don't know the best practice for this as I am no SQL shark. I have below added the two different outputs I have before I do the query. I don't know which is easier to work with for this, but the code example is for the list of elements.

**Output**

```
['testuser', 'AskeMeyer']
```

and

```
[('testuser',), ('AskeMeyer',)]
```

**Code to query**

```
   try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USER, password=PASS, sslmode='require', sslrootcert="SSLCERTIFICATE")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        var_string = ', '.join(map(str, res))
        sql = 'INSERT INTO users_from_group(name) VALUES %s;' % var_string)
        cur.execute(sql)
```

**error from above**

```
Database connection failed due to syntax error at or near ")"
```

Comment: You need `('testuser'), ('AskeMeyer')`. But `var_string` contains `testuser, AskeMeyer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use brackets and quotes in your insert statement, for example:

```py
var_string = ', '.join([f"(\"{name}\")" for name in ['testuser', 'AskeMeyer']])
```

Also, there is a bracket at the end of your sql statement which causes the syntax error:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO users_from_group(name) VALUES %s;' % var_string)
```

Should be

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO users_from_group(name) VALUES %s;' % var_string
```

Comment: I get "Database connection failed due to column "testuser" does not exist" - i only have one column called "name" where i want to add all the names from the list

Comment: Makes sense, since testuser is not interpreted as String, to fix it we have to use quotes. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, still not correct, its like it is looking for the column name as the list. But the list should just be dumped into the column with the name "name" i get this error now - Database connection failed due to column "AskeMeyer" does not exist

Comment: LINE 1: INSERT INTO users_from_group(name) VALUES ("AskeMeyer"), ("t...

Comment: Okay, did it work now or do you stell get an error?

Answer (score 0):

it's not the proper way to store lists.
you should save it as json :

```
json.dumps(['testuser', 'AskeMeyer'] )
```

then save it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var_string = '(' + ','.join(map(str, res)) + ')'
sql = 'INSERT INTO users_from_group(name) VALUES %s;' % var_string
```

Comment: did not work  - "Database connection failed due to syntax error at or near ")"